# CSS Layout not extending wrapper

Tags: html, css

I am trying to build a website that has three floating columns in the middle of the page. I have a container wrapping around everthing but it will not extend fully.  Is there something I am doing wrong?

Thanks

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
    <title></title>
       <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/style.css">
 </head>
 <body>
     <div id="container">
         <div id="header">
             <div id="navbar"></div>
         </div>
         <div id="topper">This is the Topper</div>
         <div id="colone">This is column one</div>
         <div id="coltwo">This is column two</div>
         <div id="colthree">This is colum three</div>
         <div id="footer">This is the footer</div>
     </div>
 </body>
 </html>

 @charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */
#container
{
    background-color:#CCC;
    min-height:100%;
}
#header
{
    background-color: #000;
    width:100%;
    float:left;
}
#navbar
{
    background-color: #FFF;
    border-radius: 10px;
    height:75px;
    width:70%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top:10px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    border-radius:10px;
}
#topper
{
    background-color:#000;
    height: 175px;
}
#colone
{
    background-color:#FFF;
    float:left;
    margin-left:15px;
    margin-top:-20px;
    height:150px;
}
#coltwo
{
    background-color:#FFF;
    float:left;
    margin-left:15px;
    margin-top:-20px;
    height:150px;
}
#colthree
{
    background-color:#FFF;
    float:left;
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-top:-20px;
    height:150px;
}

#footer
{
}
```

Comment: you need like this http://jsfiddle.net/ilmkamil/MEhL9/1/ ?

Comment: "it will not extend fully" can you clarify what you mean by this please? ... extend to the bottom of the window?

Answer (score 1):

You need to [clear](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html) your float. This is what it looks like.

http://jsfiddle.net/ZT59d/

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="header">
        <div id="navbar"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="topper">This is the Topper</div>
    <div id="colone">This is column one</div>
    <div id="coltwo">This is column two</div>
    <div id="colthree">This is colum three</div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div id="footer">This is the footer</div>
</div>

#container {
    background-color:#CCC;
    min-height:100%;
}
#header {
    background-color: #000;
    width:100%;
    float:left;
}
#navbar {
    background-color: #FFF;
    border-radius: 10px;
    height:75px;
    width:70%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top:10px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    border-radius:10px;
}
#topper {
    background-color:#000;
    height: 175px;
}
#colone {
    background-color:#FFF;
    float:left;
    margin-left:15px;
    margin-top:-20px;
    height:150px;
}
#coltwo {
    background-color:#FFF;
    float:left;
    margin-left:15px;
    margin-top:-20px;
    height:150px;
}
#colthree {
    background-color:#FFF;
    float:left;
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-top:-20px;
    height:150px;
}

.clear
{
    clear:both;
}
#footer {
}
```

If you don't mind, I'm going to give you some suggestions on how to improve your code.

First, you're using HTML5 but you're not using some of the new elements. Let's replace them.

```
<header>
    <nav></nav>
</header>
<main>
    <div id="topper">This is the Topper</div>
    <div id="colone">This is column one</div>
    <div id="coltwo">This is column two</div>
    <div id="colthree">This is colum three</div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</main>
<footer>This is the footer</footer>
```

You're also using ids for everything. Trust me, you don't want to do that. Realistically, you should be using ids sparingly. I'm at the point now that the only time I use an id is if I need to target something with javascript.

```
<header>
    <nav></nav>
</header>
<main>
    <div id="topper">This is the Topper</div>
    <div class="column">This is column one</div>
    <div class="column">This is column two</div>
    <div class="column">This is colum three</div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</main>
<footer>This is the footer</footer>
```

Here's what you're new css would look like.

```
body {
    background-color:#CCC;
    min-height:100%;
}
header {
    background-color: #000;
    width:100%;
    float:left;
}
nav {
    background-color: #FFF;
    border-radius: 10px;
    height:75px;
    width:70%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top:10px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    border-radius:10px;
}
#topper {
    background-color:#000;
    height: 175px;
}
.column {
    background-color:#FFF;
    float:left;
    margin-left:15px;
    margin-top:-20px;
    height:150px;
}
.clear {
    clear:both;
}
```

I left `#topper` in because it's unusual. It's hard for me to tell exactly what you're trying to achieve with it.

Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZT59d/1/) with everything together.

Comment: some good information on clearing floats here: http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/ ...the clearfix hack is a common fix for web projects

Comment: Thanks for your help Sam and also for the tips.

Answer (score 0):

Easy way to fix this is to add such CSS rules:

```
#footer
{
    clear: both;
}
#container {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/m_ms27/XETf5/)

Obviously, you have some problems understanding how `float` property works. You should investigate it more careful. Especially I would recommend to check out [clearfix](http://www.webtoolkit.info/css-clearfix.html#.U2orEFR_v4J) hack.